# Angular custom Validator checkbox

Tags: angular, validation

i am making a custom validator in Angular. the purpose of the validator is that it makes certain fields required when a checkbox is checked. At the moment the input that it validates is always required and not just when the checkbox is checked.
here is my validator code:

```
import { FormControl, AbstractControl } from "../../../node_modules/@angular/forms";

   export function validateCheckbox(control:AbstractControl){
    const val = control.value;
    const check = control.root.get('checkbox'); //i think the problem is here: if i do .value i get an error

    if (check) {
        if (val === null || val === undefined || val === '') {
            return {
                validate: {
                  valid: false
                }
              };
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

My component using the validator:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Customer } from '../account/models/customer.model';
import { validateCheckbox } from './customValidators';


@Component({
  selector: 'caredeal-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]],
      firstName:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]],
      email:['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]],
      telephone:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]],
      mobilePhone:['',Validators.minLength(10)],
      type:[''],
      checkbox:[false],
      companyName:['',Validators.minLength(2)],
      rizivNumber:[''],
      taxNumber:['',Validators.minLength(2)],
      streetName:['', Validators.required],
      houseNumber:['',validateCheckbox],
      bus:[''],
      zipCode:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4)]],
      place:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]]
    })
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

My html code, the checkbox is at the end of the code, validator is used on housenumber input.

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Account informatie</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Naam">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Voornaam">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" formControlName="telephone" placeholder="Telefoon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" formControlName="mobilePhone" placeholder="GSM">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="sel1">Type klant:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="type">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Bedrijfsgegevens</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="companyName" placeholder="Bedrijfsnaam">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control"formControlName="rizivNumber" placeholder="RIZIV-nummer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="taxNumber" placeholder="BTW-nummer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Afleveradres</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="streetName" placeholder="Straatnaam">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sound-5-1"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="houseNumber" placeholder="Huisnummer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="bus" placeholder="Bus">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="zipCode" placeholder="Postcode">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="place" placeholder="Plaats">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox"  name="">Facturatie adres is verschillend van afleveradres<br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button type="submit" [disabled] = "!registerForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

## My Solution

Looks like you don't need a custom validator. it is eassier to subscribe to the checkbox and then update the form according to the value of the checkbox. This is my component code now:

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  bool:boolean = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]],
      firstName:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]],
      email:['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]],
      telephone:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]],
      mobilePhone:['',Validators.minLength(10)],
      type:[''],
      checkbox:[false],
      companyName:['',Validators.minLength(2)],
      rizivNumber:[''],
      taxNumber:['',Validators.minLength(2)],
      streetName:['', Validators.required],
      houseNumber:[''],
      bus:[''],
      zipCode:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4)]],
      place:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]]
    })
    this.formControlValueChanged();
   }

   setNotification(): void {
    this.bool = !this.bool;
    if(this.bool){
      this.registerForm.root.get('houseNumber').setValidators(Validators.required);
    }else{
      this.registerForm.root.get('houseNumber').clearValidators();
    }
    this.registerForm.get('houseNumber').updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  formControlValueChanged() {
    this.registerForm.get('checkbox').valueChanges.subscribe(
        (mode: string) => {
            this.setNotification();
        });
}
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting now?

Comment: without .value no errors. it's just not working: with .value error: ncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at FormControl.validateCheckbox [as validator]

Comment: `const check = control.root.get('checkbox:checked');` try with this one.

Comment: You can't access to anofther form control form custome validator you have to create form group validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar below:

[image]

Above I make the phone required only if the `Send Notifications` radio button is set to text.

I do this using the following code:

```
  setNotification(notifyVia: string): void {
    const phoneControl = this.customerForm.get('phone');
    if (notifyVia === 'text') {
      phoneControl.setValidators(Validators.required);
    } else {
      phoneControl.clearValidators();
    }
    phoneControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

So instead of building a validator, this simply adds or clears the required validator on the field. In my example, I only set the validators for one control (`phoneControl`), but you could easily set the validators for any number of controls.

This code is called every time the radio button changes using code as shown below. You'd instead need to call the setNotification each time the checkbox is checked:

```
this.customerForm.get('notification').valueChanges
  .subscribe(value => this.setNotification(value));
```

Comment: this will solve the problem but `clear Validators` will clear all others validators on the from control

Comment: Where do i set de code where it subscribes to the buttons? Currently trying your solution.

Comment: i made some changes to your code, it is working now. thanks for the help! will post my solution for other people to see

Comment: @JorenVermeir yes this work for you but formGroup Validator is more cleaner and the place to return validation error rather than set nd clear the validation , this is my point

Answer (score 0):

you can't access to another form control from custome validators you have to create a custome form validator

```
export  function validateCheckbox(fg) {
  if (fg.get('checkbox').value) {
    let val = fg.get('text').value;
    if (val === null || val === undefined || val === '') {
      return {
        validate: {
          valid: false
        }
      };
    } else { // text control has a value
      return null;
    }
  } else { // checkbox value is false 
    return null;
  }
}
```

component

```
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      checkbox: [false],
      text: ['']
    }, { validator: validateCheckbox })
  }
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xthukn)

[FormBuilder/Group](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group)

Comment: But how do i only make the field required when the checkbox is checked?